# Django-cms urls

Tags: python, django, url, django-cms

I am a newbie to django-cms, and with a bit of struggle I managed to install it on my pc. Now I have created a page in it. Now when I am viewing that page, the url is

```
http://localhost:8000/first/?preview
```

I tried to access the page with the url,

```
http://localhost:8000/first/
```

But its not showing anything. 
I also updated the url in overwrite url, but no success. :(
Is there something which I am missing?

Edit 1 --
This is the error

```
> Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:     http://localhost:8000/first/

URLs.py -

    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^myproject/', include('myproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns

settings.py -

    # Django settings for myproject project.
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'database.sqlite',
                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")


# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'z5kxo4ygzw&tqnx@=f+pc9$ptjwix^!h9ja#6_&e4%-_1l3u8u'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
)


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.media.PlaceholderMediaMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates")

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'appmedia',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',


)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your urls.py, views.py, and possibly the actual error output with debugging turned on?

Comment: any one to help me out?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your urls.py may be incorrect.  I don't see where your project's package is being imported.  I am assuming cms is the name of the app and not the project here. It also looks like you may not actually be defining your urlpatterns variable at all, but I'm not sure since the formatting got a bit funky.  If your project was named myproject the urls.py should look like

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^', include('myproject.cms.urls')),
)
```

Comment: I tried it, and my project name is myproject. But no success. And when i changed it to 'myproject.cms.urls' its not even showing the django-cms home page now.

Comment: Do you have another urls.py within your cms app which maps "first/" to an actual view defined in views.py?

Comment: nope, but I think the problem is solved now. I didnt checked the is publish check box in the page editing section. I checked it now, and its working fine now.

Comment: Ah, cool, good to hear.  I still think the urls.py looks off, but that could just be due to the formatting causing me to miss something.  If it's working, then go with it.

Comment: thanks mate, one last question. How to learn django-cms. I want to build an application which will have a admin panel and admin will upload products to different categories. How to move ahead with the application using django-cms?

Comment: @mad_programmer, that's a separate question that you should post separately for.

Comment: @jmich, his urls are correct, provided that the cms application is on the python path, which it probably is (site-packages) if installed via setup.py

Comment: @mad_programmer yeah, probably good for a separate question as Josh Smeaton said so that you can get more/better answers.  I used The Django Book (http://www.djangobook.com/) to get up to speed with Django myself.  I found it more clear than most of the tutorials I had tried before.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?  The correct answer is the one by @ojii.

Comment: Not sure. I agree that it looks like my answer was not correct.  I see I commented on the urls.py being formatted weird, so I'm hoping that my mistake was purely due to that and not realizing that it was actually working with the ?preview bit rather than me just being stupid that day.

Answer (score 6):

The urls.py posted in the question is correct. The thing with ?preview is that it allows logged-in administrators to see pages which are not published. To be able to see the page without ?preview, you have to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

in django 2.4.2, after making changes to page just click "Publish Draft" button on top-right.This will make the page public and can be viewed from the url `http://localhost:8000/first/`